# How to Insert new documents according to a condition that can be appliyed on one of them

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection where I store unique uID for a user and I also have to register them manually. While registration I pass multiple IDs in an array and now I want to query if any of those uIDs provided while registration match existing uID from registered collection, I want to return those document or simply a truth value which will tell that users exist so that I abort registration and assign another id for a user.

```
const uniqueIDs = [ "123", "156", "148"]
```

If required I can run map function to get these values as object of arrays such as

```
[
{
    uID : "123",
},
{
    uID : "156",
},
{
    uID : "148",
},
]
```

Example from existing collection:

```
{
    uID : "123",
    country : "abc"
},
{
    uID : "486",
    country : "def"
},
{
    uID : "958",
    country : "jkl"
},
```

Now my question is can I query my collection from mapped array or array of uiDs so that I find existing documents?
If none documents found, can I insert multiple documents from this unique uID from insertMany like function?

Comment: Is [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_fpOd4DYXJ9) what are you looking for?

Comment: Yes and how to insert multiple documents if none of these IDs match?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for this, although I would say this is more of an hack than a common practice.

You could do something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      addition: [
        {$limit: 1},
        {$project: {
            _id: 0,
            data: [
              {
                uID: "333",
                country: "defrr"
              },
              {
                uID: "222",
                country: "jklyy"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      found: [
        {$match: {"uID": {$in: ["123", "156", "148"]}}}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $cond: [{$lt: [{$size: "$found"}, 1]},
          {$arrayElemAt: ["$addition", 0]}, {data:'errorCase'}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$data.data"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data.data"}
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "collection",
      on: "uID"
    }
  }
])
```

This is an aggregation pipeline with a `$merge` step at the end, in order to insert new documents into the collection. The `$facet` steps builds the documents you want to insert and checks the condition. The `$project` with the `$cond` override it with a data that will return an error in case the condition founds existing `uID`.

There are limitation to this hack. First you need to have at least one document in your collection before running it, since it uses it as a base to create the new documents. Second, in order to use the `$merge` step you need to create a unique index on the `uID`.

At the end, if there are no documents with the `uID` in the list it will insert the new documents. If there are documents with the `uID` in the list it will return an error.

Comment: If it works for you please accept it, so it will be easier for others to find it.